PostCSS Output is Not Showing
Hey guys I'm pretty new to PostCSS and I have an issue where my my changes are not showing up. I npm install the PostCSS Cli, dev dependencies, autoprefixer for my plugin and placed it in the post.config.js file. I have my index.html file inside the dist folder and my input.css in my src folder where i make style changes.
In my package.json i have my script as
"scripts": {
    "watch:css": "postcss src/input.css -o dist/styles.css -w",
    "build:css": "postcss src/input.css -o dist/styles.css"
  },

and when i ran npm run build:css , my styles chasnges from the input.css did not update.
